# Error whilst trying to run javafx application

Tags: javafx

Im having an error when im trying to run my application in javafx and its pointing to this xml file. the eror is as follows
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,6]Message: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

can someone help me out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.Reflection?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.EndOfDayController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="eodAnchor" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="410.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="-10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <JFXTextField labelFloat="true" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="73.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="186.0" promptText="Date" />
            <Label layoutX="99.0" layoutY="83.0" text="End Of Day" />
            <JFXTextField labelFloat="true" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="208.0" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="186.0" promptText="items" unFocusColor="#4d4d4d" />
            <Label layoutX="97.0" layoutY="110.0" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="96.0" text="Eod Status" />
            <Label layoutX="97.0" layoutY="172.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="88.0" text="Next Pos Date" />
            <JFXComboBox labelFloat="true" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="147.0" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="186.0" unFocusColor="#f50a0a">
               <effect>
                  <Reflection/>
               </effect>
            </JFXComboBox>
            <Label layoutX="97.0" layoutY="234.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="88.0" text="Total Items Sold" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnOkEOD" buttonType="RAISED" layoutX="83.0" layoutY="272.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="66.0" prefWidth="262.0" ripplerFill="#3145f5" text="Ok">
               <stylesheets>
                  <URL value="@main.css" />
               </stylesheets>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXTextField labelFloat="true" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="119.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="174.0" promptText="Status" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Ensure that `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is in the first line without any leading whitespace.

Comment: alright thanks very much